# How to pull the data partially from firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanna pull whole data from the firebase database and access that without change data.

```
firebase.database().ref(‘someBigNode’).once(‘value’, (snapshot) => {
    //do something
}
```

But it will cost many memory.

May I ask how to pull whole data partially and save memory?

Answer (score 4):

When you read data from Firebase Database with the JavaScript (or iOS or Android) SDK, it will always read complete nodes. So the only way to retrieve less data is to retrieve a node lower in the JSON tree.

If you find you need to retrieve a part of each node under `someBigNode`, you should split that part of each node out into a top-level node of their own `importantBitsOfSomeBigNode`.

It's unfortunately hard to be more helpful without a more concrete example of your data structure and the bits you're trying to retrieve (and the reason why those bits are special).

Comment: I try to use startAt, endAt or limitFirst to do that in a loop, but it make me feel pain :(

Comment: Sorry, that's a rather unactionable statement. If you still have a question, please update your question with the code *and* the data that you're querying. Otherwise, we're taking blind guesses beyond explaining how Firebase works - as I did above.